# How to use iOS debug app on iPhone while disconnected?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, debugging, mobile-application

I made a flutter app and tried to build on iPhone. It works while debugging is connected. But if I try to exit and relaunch the app or disconnect cable, it would not launch again and keeps crashing.
How can I use the app while Xcode debugging is disconnected?

Answer (score 15):

Run `flutter run --release` in the terminal and that'll allow you to run a production version app on your iOS device without debugging connected.

Answer (score 1):

From Xcode, you can change the **Build Configuration** of the **Run Schema** easily. To do this, click on **Runner** -> **Edit Scheme**, then go in the **Run** tab, choose "**Release**" in the **Build Configuration** drop down menu. To install the application, run the configuration again.

See Step 4 in [this page](https://flutteragency.com/how-to-build-flutter-app-in-release-mode-for-ios/) for screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

If you only `Start Debugging` after this you can disconnect cable and will work. If you after `Restart Debugging` after this if you disconnect cable app will be crashing. I think you restart debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can already able to debug with cable.

- `flutter build ios`
- connect cable
- `flutter install` , if more than 1 device option is available, terminal will prompt you to choose the device for installation.
- now you can disconnect cable

Comment: theres no need for a provisioning profile for this?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible for now, you should build app only on Release mode (from XCode) to make it run on Physical phone.